# Django - How to add a value to each tuple in values_list

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a `values_list`:

```
mylist = Region.objects.values_list('region_id','region').order_by('region')

for x in mylist: print(x)
```

returns

```
(2, 'Africa')
(9, 'Antarctic')
(3, 'Asia Temperate')
...
```

I would like to add a third element to each tuple to get

```
(2, 'Africa','x')
(9, 'Antarctic','y')
(3, 'Asia Temperate',x')
```

I have tried:

```
for a in mylist:
    if some condition:
        a + ('x',)
    else:
        a + ('y',)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add it back to a new list, like:

```
new_list=[]
for a in my_list:
    if some condition:
        new_list.append(a+('x',))
    else:
        new_list.append(a+('y',))
```

Or best is one-liner list comprehension:

```
new_list=[i+('x',) if some condition else i+('y',) for i in my_list]
```

Both cases `new_list` will be desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new tuple and initialize it with an iterable, something like this:

```
for a in mylist:
    if some condition:
        b = a + ('x',)
    else:
        b = a + ('y',)
    do something with b
```

or something similar.

Comment: Edited, Tuples are immutable has nothing to do with this, so?